# vary length hash collision on deterministic block cipher

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

[image]

I am trying to learn attack on hash collision. I guess for this scheme, it might be possible to use messages with different lengths to find a pair of same ciphertexts. An attempt is to use the same first block, and let `M1 = M[1]` and `M2 = M[1]M[2]`. Then, it might be possible to find a collision because the first one outputs `C[1]` and the second one outputs the `C[2]`, but I am a little confused about how to analyze `M[2]` so that they form a collision.

Comment: Is $K$ public knowledge, or do you only have Oracle access to $H_k$ (for some unknown $k$)?

Comment: K is known to the adversary, so u can actually calculate Hk without using an oracle but by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to learn, and so I'll just give you a hint:

- You know the value `C[1]`; how do you find a *fixed point*, that is, a value `M[2]` that maps `C[1]` to itself (so `C[1] = C[2]`)
- Further hint: it's easier to work backwards; start at the target value of `C[2]`, and figure out how to select `M[2]` so that `B[2]` is something appropriate

Comment: I figured out. It's little tricky, which doesn't make sense to me in the first glance, but it seems like u can duplicate M[1] but still get the same hash value if E(M[1]) = 0^128, which is really smart when I first noticed this approach.

Comment: @Turingtest: no, I don't believe that is correct; what would `M[2]` need to be to make sure that `B[2] = C[2]`?

Comment: Consider AES = E, then C1 output C[1] = E(E(M[1] xor 0^128) xor M[1]) = E(E(M[1]) xor M[1]) = E(0^128 xor M[1]) = E(M[1]) = 0^128.                                                                         C[2] = E(E(M[2] xor C[1]) xor M[2]) = E(E(M[2] xor o^128) xor M[2]) = E(E(M[2]) xor M[2])               if M[1] = M[2], C[2] = E(E[M[1]) xor M[1]) = E(0^128 xor M[1]) = E(M[1]) = 0^128. Then C[1] = C[2].